# does face book sharer.php still work for custom comment

Tags: php, facebook

The code below only sends the url, title and summary don't get sent,  I heard something about having to use the facebook api, would like to keep it simple if it can be done without.  Thanks

```
 http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?p[title]=my%title&p[summary]=my%summery&p[url]=the%url
```

Answer (score 0):

no the facebook sharer.php is not logger support custom parameters

you can manage this by creating meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

or use facebook feed dailog box

here use can learn how to use

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4